# How to get cell index in DevExpress Gridview?

Tags: c#, gridview, devexpress

I have 6 columns on gridview (shown as figure). How to get cell index? For example, when I handle double click `Durum(Status)` column or `Detay(Detail)` column on gridview, return index numbers. Actually I want to do that when I double click different cell of the row, happen different things. For example I double click the status cell of the row, change the status or I double click the detail cell of the same row, open new form. How can I do this?

[image: Figure]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
private void gridView1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
   var gv = sender as GridView;
   var rowIndex = gv.FocusedRowHandle;
   var columnIndex = gv.FocusedColumn.VisibleIndex;
}
```